# Talks and Workshops at professional conferences like PyCon and various un-conferences

Tags: phd, conference, cv, seminars, workshop

How do you present talks and workshops that you have conducted at various open source events and professional conference and events like un-conferences, in your academic CV and application form for PhD?

Also, do they have the same standing as those organised purely by academic institutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List them the same way as you would any other talks.  They may not have the same standing in terms of content, but they show that you have practice grasping new material and presenting it, which is important for Ph.D students and graduates to be able to do.